# Power BI, DAX - Count number of closed cases by day, when "open date" is establishing the relationship to the Date table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a fact table (Cases) similar to this one:

```
>     Case Number   Date Opened Date Closed Status
>     C123564659    06/11/2019  07/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564656    06/11/2019  07/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564660    07/11/2019  07/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564655    07/11/2019  11/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564654    07/11/2019  11/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564657    07/11/2019  12/11/2019  Closed
>     C123564658    07/11/2019  14/11/2019  Closed
```

It is related to a date table (Calendar) via the "Date Opened" column.

I need to count the number of closed cases by day, that will be displayed in both a Matrix Table (where Rows = days) and Column Chart (where the X axis = days or weeks) visualizations.

If I do a simple count like:

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(Cases[Case Number]); Cases[Status] = Closed)
```

Then I just get the total amount of closed cases that match the "Date Opened" for a certain day. For example, according to the table above, I would get a total of 5 closed cases on 07/11/2019, because of the date relationship is taking only the "Date Opened" column into account to calculate the dates.

If I create a VAR to define the selected date such as:

```
VAR openedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_CALENDAR[Date])

RETURN

CALCULATE(COUNT(Cases[Case Number]); Cases[Status] = Closed; openedDate = Cases[Date Closed])
```

Then I will only get 1 closed case, because it is the only "Date Closed" that matches the "Date Opened".

So I need a way to show the actual number of cases closed in a certain day - which would be 3 cases (following the same example on 07/11/2019)

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your time.

EDIT:

I think I found the solution. I've created a DAX summarized Table with only closed cases, then I established all the relevant relationships to the DIM tables, including the Calendar table.

It seems to be working, but I would still like to hear if anyone has a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do instead of a summerized table is to create a second, passive relationship between your dim_calendar and 'Case'[Date Closed]:

[image]

Then activat this passive relationship inside a CALCULATE by using USERELATIONSHIP, like this:

```
Closed by Closing Date = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Case'[Case Number]);
    'Case'[Status] = "Closed";
    USERELATIONSHIP('Case'[Date Closed]; 'Calendar'[Date])
)
```

Then you end up with something like this:

[image]

Date is from the Calendar table and "Closed by opening Date" is the same measure as your first (without VAR).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Simple slick solution, seems to be more efficient.