# PowerBI How to Summarize by Group By for two Y Axis and two X shared axis

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to use a matrix or line stacked chart to summarize the next data

```
ITEM    |RAISED_DATE    |STATUS |CLOSED_DATE
A       |2022-12-25     |CLOSED |2023-02-31
B       |2023-01-26     |CLOSED |2023-02-02
C       |2023-01-28     |OPEN   |
D       |2023-02-01     |OPEN   |
E       |2023-02-14     |CLOSED |2023-02-06
F       |2023-02-18     |CLOSED |2023-03-02
G       |2023-02-28     |OPEN   |
H       |2023-03-03     |CLOSED |2023-03-08
```

Into this

```
PERIOD  |RAISED_QTY |CLOSED_QTY
2022-12 |1          |0
2023-01 |2          |0
2023-02 |4          |3
2023-03 |1          |2
```

I created two measures to sum the total items for raised, and the total for closed. The total values are ok but if I wan't to summarize the values according to the period then the results are not OK. I drag the meassures to the Y axis but according to the column that I put in the X axis I get different values (and none are the values I need)

If X axis = RAISED_DATE (YYYYMM)

```
PERIOD  |RAISED_QTY |CLOSED_QTY
2023-12 |1          |1
2023-01 |2          |1
2023-02 |4          |2
2023-03 |1          |1
```

If X Axis = CLOSED_DATE (YYYYMM)

```
PERIOD  |RAISED_QTY |CLOSED_QTY
        |3          |0
2023-02 |3          |3
2023-03 |2          |2
```

I try to create a calendar table and set relationships between the dates, but is still a mess. I know it is because that even when the RAISED_DATE and CLOSED_DATE is same data type, they should be like different X axis. But I can't find (or don't know) of a matrix/visual that can do this.

Please, some pointers to achieve the results I need. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was halfway to the answer! I found the answer in this post

[Power BI, DAX - Count number of closed cases by day, when "open date" is establishing the relationship to the Date table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095523/power-bi-dax-count-number-of-closed-cases-by-day-when-open-date-is-establi?rq=1)

For those who came with a similar problem.

1. You have to create the calendar table (a table with all the dates to relate to other date columns)
2. Create the two relationships from the Calendar[Date] to the Table[Raised_Date] and from the Calendar[Date] to the Table[Closed_Date]. By default it uses the primary (active) relationship to calculate (I set Raised_Date as active)
3. Create the secondary measures with CALCULATE and be sure to specify which relationship the measure will use after the filter with the USERELATIONSHIP

   ```
    RaisedQtyMeasure = COUNT(Table[ITEM_CODE])
    ClosedQtyMeasure = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[ITEM_CODE]), Table[STATUS] = "CLOSED", USERELATIONSHIP('Table'[CLOSED_DATE], 'Calendar'[Date]))
   ```
4. In the chart you can set the Calendar[Date] in the X Axis and the two created measures in the Y Axis

Hope it helps!